# How does connect work without mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was reading the example docs for redux and I found this example of a container component. Can someone explain why in this case mapDispatchToProps is not needed here. As well, how is the function getting the dispatch function?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
let input

return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`connect()(AddTodo)` will pass `dispatch` as a `prop to AddTodo` component, which is still useful even without state or predefined actions. Thats the reason `mapDispatchToProps` is not needed in your code

Now in your component `let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {` you are destructuring your props to only access `dispatch`.

If you make use of `mapDispatchToProps` you will make your `addTodo` action available as a prop to your component and then call it like `this.props.addTodo`. So the above approach is an alternative. It depends on you to choose what you feel comfortable with

`connect` just passes `store / dispatch` through React context so you don't have to pass the store through many components. You don't have to use connect though. Any module / HOC pattern could work, connect just happens to be a convenient thing to use.

Using `dispatch` in the component or using `mapDispatchToProps` are one and the same thing.

However using `mapDispatchToProps` gives you much more flexibility in structuring your code and having all the action creators at one place.

As per the **[docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)**:

> **[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function):**
>
> **If an object is passed**, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.
>
> **If a function is passed,** it will be given dispatch as the first parameter. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses
>   dispatch to bind action creators in your own way. (Tip: you may use
>   the `bindActionCreators()` helper from Redux.)
>
> If your `mapDispatchToProps` function is declared as taking two
>   parameters, it will be called with dispatch as the first parameter and
>   the props passed to the connected component as the second parameter,
>   and will be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new
>   props. (The second parameter is normally referred to as ownProps by
>   convention.)
>
> If you do not supply your own `mapDispatchToProps` function or object
>   full of action creators, the default `mapDispatchToProps`
>   implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props.

Comment: In case I don't need `mapDispatchToProps`, should I pass an empty object or just leave it empty and let it inject the `dispatch` into my component. Does it affect performance in any way?

Comment: @Norbert In case you don't need mapDispatchToProps you can simply avoid the second argument altogether. All these are different ways to do the same thing and hence don't have much performance difference

Answer (score 0):

People tend to write `react` in two ways. One is `class` based approach which you would normally encounter. It basically uses classes.

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={}
    }
    render(){
        return(

            //
        );
    }
}
```

and other is `functional approach`.

```
const App = (props) => {
​
    return(
        <div><h2>{{props.name}}</h2></div>
    )
}
```

So, in functional approach you can pass data as `arguments` to your components. 
So, if you have passed `dispatch` from parent component to this component in `props` . You can access it using `props.dispatch`.

Comment: I understand that concept but I don't know how in this case the component is receiving dispatch. I was under the impression that to receive the dispatch function, I would need to pass a mapDispatchToProps which in this case is not so. Is it the case that just because I pass the component to the connect function it is somehow receives dispatch now?

Comment: dispatch would be passed to this component from parent component as a prop.

Comment: but this approach is not good. You should use connect to pass dispatch and props. read the comment of gaearon [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1176)