# dispatch is not defined on my functions using react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-middleware

I am trying to use [react-redux-loading-bar](https://github.com/mironov/react-redux-loading-bar) to show a loading bar during fetching data from API servers, I don't use promise middleware so I decided to use it without, the example says do this

```
import { showLoading, hideLoading } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

dispatch(showLoading())
// do long running stuff
dispatch(hideLoading())
```

And it gives me this.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined
```

I had similar issues with other libraries and gave up that time, this time I want to actually understand how this works, so any info is greatly appreciated. Heres the code that causing the error, speicifc function and class names stripped.

```
import React from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { showLoading, hideLoading } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'


import * as xxxxxActions from '../../actions/xxxxx'


class xxxxxx extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleclick = this.handleclick.bind(this)
    }

    handleclick(){
        dispatch(showLoading())
        asynchronousGetFunction( target_url, function (data) {
            dispatch(hideLoading())
        })
    }

    render() {

        return  <li onClick={this.handleclick}>yyyyyyy</li>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps( state ){
    return {
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, state) {

    return {
        xxxxxActions: bindActionCreators( xxxxxActions, dispatch )
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(xxxxxx)
```

Comment: When you use bindActionCreators, every action creator is wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly using props. So to dispatch, in your case , use something like this.props.xxxxxActions.yourActionToDispatch()

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670146/why-is-there-no-need-for-a-mapdispatchtoprops-function-here/41671030#41671030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass dispatch function to your props:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, state) {
    return { 
        xxxxxActions: ....,
        showLoading: function () {
            dispatch(showLoading());
        },
        hideLoading: function () {
            dispatch(hideLoading());
        },
    };
}
```

Then, use it in your component:

```
this.props.showLoading();
...
this.props.hideLoading();
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, however encountering some unforeseen errors due to the fix, I think its not because of errors in this answer but something unrelated in my code, will mark it as the answer as soon as I get to the bottom of it.

Comment: btw whats happening is when I call showLoading it blows everything in the store tied to the xxxxActions

Comment: I think I understand whats happening, they are getting dispatched as xxxxActions events, thus hitting my reducer for xxxxActions, where it should be hitting the reducer for  react-redux-loading-bar

Answer (score 2):

Once you `connect` your component, `dispatch` becomes a `prop`. The same applies for `xxxxxActions`...

In that case, the handle would be:

```
handleclick(){
  this.props.dispatch(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use "dispatch" in components. Bind your functions with dispatch in mapDispatchToProps.

Read more about mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: Yeah I feel I'm misunderstanding how dispatch works, thanks for the tip