# --How do I implement mapDispatchToProps()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was looking for the documentation for both `connect()` and `mapDispatchToProps()`

http://redux.js.org/?q=connect()

But also I found that I already have access to `props.dispatch()` for the code below:

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');
const AppRedux = connect()(App);

ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRedux></AppRedux>
  </Provider>

, app);
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670146/why-is-there-no-need-for-a-mapdispatchtoprops-function-here/41671030#41671030

Answer (score 1):

By using the `connect` only, you already have access to `dispatch` through `this.props.dispatch` (as you have mentioned).

However, what `mapDispatchToProps` does is automatically bind your redux actions also via props. For example:

```
import customAction from 'actions-directory-in-your-app'

const mapStateToProps = () => {} // no implementing anything for example purposes
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({ customAction })

const AppRedux = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

From now on, `customAction` also becomes a prop just like `dispatch`.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to connect takes an object, so you can use of ES6 syntax and avoid the use of mapDispatchToProps.

```
    import { yourAction } from './your_actions_folder'
    class Home extends Component{
        ....
        //For dispatch a action you only call the action Creator
        this.props.yourAction()
    }

     export default connect(mapStateToProps,{yourAction})(Home)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient way to do mapDispatchToProps is as follows:

```
import * as myActions from './myActionsFile';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

...

 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
     actions: bindActionCreators(myActions , dispatch)
    };
  }
```

And your 'myActionsFile' would have something like:

```
export function loadSomeObject(object) {
 return {type: types.LOAD_SOME_OBJECT, object};
}

export function saveSomeObject(object) {
 return {type: types.SAVE_SOME_OBJECT, object};
}
```

Redux's bindActionCreator helps you bind your actions on the fly.