# Multiple actionCreators in single component

Tags: reactjs, controller, redux

I want to have multiple actionCreators dispatched into one component. I know you can do this with state

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => Object.assign({}, state.search, state.resources),
    ResourcesState.actionCreators// i have another actionCreator I want to add 
)(Home) as typeof Home;
```

But not sure the syntax to do this with actionCreators. I have read into

> mapDispatchToProps

But not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to set up dispatching of Redux actions in React components:

1. Use `connect(mapState)(MyComponent)`.  By default, your component will be given `props.dispatch`, and you can call `props.dispatch({type : "SOME_ACTION"})`.
2. Pass a `mapDispatchToProps` function as the second argument to connect.  Inside, you can create new function references that call `dispatch`:

   ```
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
            addTodo : (text) => dispatch({type : "ADD_TODO", text})
      }
   }
   ```
3. You can also use the Redux `bindActionCreators` utility instead:

   ```
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
       return bindActionCreators({addTodo, toggleTodo}, dispatch);
   }
   ```
4. Finally, you can pass an object full of action creators directly to `connect`:

   ```
   const actions = {addTodo, toggleTodo};
   export default connect(mapState, actions)(MyComponent);
   ```

I highly recommend the fourth approach, which I also talk about in my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Why Use Action Creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).

Answer (score 0):

`mapDispatchToProps` is the second argument in `connect`. So for example:

```
import customAction from 'actions-directory-in-your-app'

const mapStateToProps = () => {} // no implementing anything for example purposes
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({ customAction })

const ConnectedContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YourContainer)
```

`customAction` becomes now a prop in `YourContainer` so you can use it the same way other props within your component.

Answer (score 0):

the Second argument to connect takes an `object` or a `functio`n so you can add

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => Object.assign({}, state.search, state.resources),

    {
         ResourcesState.actionCreators,
         some_other_action_creators,
         some_more
    }
)(Home) as typeof Home;
```

Also read through this answer on Stackoverflow for more information on how to use action creators

[Why is there no need for a mapDispatchToProps function here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670146/why-is-there-no-need-for-a-mapdispatchtoprops-function-here/41671030#41671030)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to connect takes an object, so you can use of ES6 syntax and avoid the use of `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
import { yourAction } from './your_actions_folder'
class Home extends Component{
....
//For dispatch a action you only call the action Creator
this.props.yourAction()
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{yourAction})(Home)
```