# using bindActionCreators, this.props.dispatch in react-redux disptach vs redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've read about bindActionCreators, i've compiled a resumen here:

```
    import { addTodo,deleteTodo } from './actionCreators'
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return { todos: state.todos }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({ addTodo, deleteTodo }, dispatch) 
    }

    *short way
        const mapDispatchToProps = {
          addTodo,
          deleteTodo
        }   
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)
```

another code use like this:

```
        function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
          let actions = bindActionCreators({ getApplications });
          return { ...actions, dispatch };
        }
```

why previous code with bindActionCreators , don't need disptach parameter?

i've tried this way to get dispatch on this.props (but not working):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators ({ appSubmitStart,  appSubmitStop}, dispatch );
};

const withState = connect(
  null ,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withGraphqlandRouter);
```

why I had to change my old short way:

```
const withState = connect(
  null ,
  { appSubmitStart,  appSubmitStop}
)(withGraphqlandRouter);
```

in order to get  this.props.dispatch()? because i neede to use dispatch for an isolated action creator inside a library with js functions. I mean before I don't needed use  "bindActionCreators", reading this doc:

https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators

"The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it."

I'm importing:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect  } from 'react-redux';
```

what is the difference using redux pure, and react-redux?
really I need "bindActionCreators" in my new code? because without this i can't see this.props.dispatch()

UPDATE:

I've found this solutions to get this.props.dispatch working:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators ({ appSubmitStart,  appSubmitStop, dispatch }, dispatch );  // to set this.props.dispatch
};
```

does anyone can explain me? how i can send same distpach like a creator ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670146/how-does-connect-work-without-mapdispatchtoprops/41671030#41671030

Also you don't need bindActionCreator and react-redux and redux are different repos and not all things are exposed entirely in redux or react-redux

Comment: thanks but the answer there is not deep; and i already read about  that, but i'm looking for deep precision in my examples, thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's clear our minds regarding some of the key concepts here:

- `bindActionCreators` is a util provided by Redux. It wraps each action creators to a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly.
- `dispatch` is a function of the Redux store. It is used to dispatch actions to store.

  - When you use the object shorthand for `mapState`, React-Redux wraps them with the store's `dispatch` using Redux's `bindActionCreators`.
- `connect` is a function provided by React-Redux. It is used to connect your component to the Redux store. When you connect your component:

  - It injects `dispatch` to your component **only if** you do not provide your customized `mapDispatchToProps` parameter.

Regarding what happened above to your code:

#### Component will not receive `dispatch` with customized `mapDispatchToProps`

In the code here:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

  return bindActionCreators(
    { appSubmitStart, appSubmitStop, dispatch }, // a bit problematic here, explained later
    dispatch 
  );  // to set this.props.dispatch
};
```

You are providing your own `mapDispatch`, therefore your component will **not** receive `dispatch`. Instead, it will rely on your returned object to contain the action creators wrapped around by `dispatch`.

As you may feel it is easy to make mistake here. It is suggested that you use the object shorthand directly, feeding in all the action creators your component will need. React-Redux binds each one of those with `dispatch` for you, and do not give `dispatch` anymore. (See [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/255) for more discussion.)

#### Writing customized `mapState` and inject `dispatch` manually

However, if you do need `dispatch` specifically alongside other action dispatchers, you will need to define your `mapDispatch` this way:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    appSubmitStart: () => dispatch(appSubmitStart),
    appSubmitStop: () => dispatch(appSubmitStop),
    dispatch,
  };
};
```

#### Using `bindActionCreators`

This is exactly what `bindActionCreators` does. Therefore, you can simplify a bit by using Redux's `bindActionCreators`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    { appSubmitStart, appSubmitStop }, // do not include dispatch here
    dispatch
  );
};
```

As mentioned above, the problem to include `dispatch` in the first argument is that it essentially gets it wrapped around by `dispatch`. You will be calling `dispatch(dispatch)` when you call `this.props.dispatch`.

However, `bindActionCreators` does not return the object with `dispatch`. It's passed in for it to be called internally, it does not give it back to you. So you will need to include that by yourself:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators({appSubmitStart, appSubmitStop}, dispatch), 
    dispatch
  };
};
```

Hope it helped! And please let me know if anything here is unclear :)

Answer (score 3):

I have made some changes to your code please try this

```
import * as Actions from './actionCreators'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


const mapStateToProps = (state)=>(
    {
        todos: state.todos
    }
)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=> (
    bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch) 
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)
```

Comment: thanks by my code is working, i need only explanation about three cases